# How to get into psql of a running postgres container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, fig

I created a postgres container using the tutorial on the [fig website](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019020915/http://www.fig.sh/django.html). I named the container **db**.

The container is running and my app connects to it fine. I tried to run the command `fig run db psql` with the **db** container running and got the error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How can I get into the `psql` interface in the running **db** container?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

*fig* will create a *docker container* with a different name than the one used in the `fig.yml` file.

I got it working by finding the container name with `docker ps` and looking at the *NAMES* column.

Then running the `psql` command in the running container with `docker exec -ti NAME_OF_CONTAINER psql -U YOUR_POSTGRES_USERNAME`

Important Note:

- `docker exec` runs the `psql`command on a running container
- `docker run` will start a new container.

---

## Update

*fig* is now called [docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose)

Comment: Good answer! It's very important to distinguish between `docker run <image>` and `docker exec <container>`. You may also just `docker exec -it  /bin/bash` **for development**.

Comment: Need to dump data, can't go docker exec -it

Comment: may also need to mention the database name like this: `docker exec -ti NAME_OF_CONTAINER psql -U YOUR_POSTGRES_USERNAME DATABASE`

Comment: This solution might work, but it answers the more specific question set out in the body of the answer, while the title of the question focuses on a more general question. I believe answers that are more general are of greater value to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of connecting with:

```
psql
```

Use the -h and -p option:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432
```

**Why did that work?**

If we run a local psql without arguments (or with incorrect arguments), psql will try to connect via a unix socket instead of tcp, because this is a tad more efficient.

However, psql's micro optimization doesn't work for our quirky setup, because our container's file system is separate by design. Even if it weren't, psql wouldn't know where to look for the socket file.

The solution is not writing a burly docker exec command, nor is it mounting a volume so that our local psql instance can find the socket in the container, **but to move the whole interaction to tcp.**

Sure this is slightly less efficient, but the very reason we are using a container is so that things work even if they are setup in different computers, **TCP is what docker containers use to communicate between processes, whether in the same machine or not.** .

To tell psql that we want to connect via TCP, we use the -h option to identify the (virtual) machine, along with -p to identify postgresql process, 5432 being the default.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432
```

psql could try to use these default parameters before giving up when given no arguments, but it choses to fail early, issue an error message and let the admin work out the connection details theirself. More information about this decision can be found in https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20191217141456.GA2413%40elch.exwg.net

Comment: implies that a psql client is installed on the local machine, but clean and logical solution to my opinion

Answer (score 20):

My 2P here; I prefer to have middlewares deployed as containers, instead of install and maintain them in the host system:

```
docker run --rm --name postgresql -p 5432:5432
-e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
-e POSTGRES_DB=demodb
-d postgres:latest
docker exec -it postgresql psql -d demodb -U admin
```

Comment: it works for me  
`docker exec -it <docker_container_name> /bin/bash`   and
`psql -d <postgres_db_name> -U <postgres_password>`

Comment: What if the container doesn't have a psql client? Which is a sensible decision.

Comment: I'm actually using third party clients (DBeaver, not to name it).

Answer (score 3):

You need to run a new container to connect to the one started by fig. This is so because the main container by default starts the service, and if you do `fig run db psql` fig will NOT start the service but run the psql client instead. See [the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/5f401753715311752f2346cdbd32bd55e7251ddd/9.4/docker-entrypoint.sh).

So to connect to the PostgreSQL service you need to run *another container* linked to the one started by fig. See https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/.

First, since fig changes the names of the containers started, check the NAMES column of the `docker ps` container after having done `fig up`. Then:

```
docker run -it --link <postgres_container_name>:postgres --rm postgres sh -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres'
```

You can do the `docker exec` trick as well as desribed by @sargas too, but the linking way sounds more canonical to me.

Comment: The --link flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Answer (score 3):

Can you post the result of `docker ps`? My guess is you need to specify the port the postgres container is exposing. Running `docker ps` should give you

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
948b1f6ebc0a        my_postgres:latest            "/usr/lib/postgresql   6 days ago          Up 6 days           0.0.0.0:49155->5432/tcp   db
```

and looking under the PORTS column for your db container you'll see the port the db is actually exposed on. In this case it's 49155, but docker will choose a random port between 49153 and 65535 if not explicitly specified at container start. You need to supply the `-p` option to psql to then target that port as such

```
psql -p 49155 ...
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Comment: For me I'll have to run `psql -h localhost -p 54322 -u postgres postgres`